# PG::Error on running rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql, pg

Ive installed PostgreSQL on my windows 7 (professional - service pack 1) machine (using the postgresql-9.1.8-2-windows-x64.exe)

Im now trying to run my rails project (via Webrick port 3000) but unfortunately i get the following error:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, check that your postgres local service is actually running (pgAdmin can tell you this).  If it is, check that the database has actually been created, and is accessible with the credentials you have configured in database.yml.  Also, check if your firewall/antivirus solution is blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused means you got back an ICMP error when you tried to connect.  Windows does not support UNIX Domain Sockets so your connection is over TCP/IP.

To troubleshoot this issue try the following steps:

1. psql on the server in question.  If it fails, make sure PostgreSQL is running etc.
2. pgAdmin from the server running webrick.  If it fails, make sure PostgreSQL is running, and that firewalls are disabled.
3. Disable firewalls, check firewall logs, event viewer, service status, etc.  Try turning off firewalls (including Windows Firewall).  Test.